# MySQL random query but with distinct values from 1 column

Tags: mysql, random, duplicates, distinct

I've a query like

```
SELECT Id, Category, Title FROM articles WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,20
```

I've 20 categories and I want 1 random article per category. How?
With this query I always have some category not selected.

Thanks

Comment: seperate table for catogories??

Answer (score 0):

try getting `DISTINCT Category` from the table, like

```
SELECT Id, DISTINCT Category, Title FROM articles WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by category. Haven't tested this, but something like:

```
SELECT Id, Category, Title FROM articles GROUP BY Category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,20
```